# GCC MIPS-32 Calling Conventions / Stack Frame Definition

Tags: gcc, embedded, mips, calling-convention, ecos

There appears to be no definitive standardized stack frame and C language calling conventions (register usage and such) for the MIPS-32 Processor Architecture. That is, it appears to be completely up to the assembler/compiler tool chain to define their own stack frame and calling conventions. I've struggled to find a definitive reference of what conventions the GCC compiler uses for MIPS-32 instruction set. I'm specially using GCC cross-compiler on Cygwin that targets a MIPS-32 core being used in an embedded environment on the eCos open source kernel.

Any references to definitive documentation about GCC for MIPS-32 in this area would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, this is a bit of a mess and is poorly documented. I would recommend:

- http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/devel/assembly/mipsabi32.pdf
- "See MIPS Run" by Dominic Sweetman
- Examining disassembled code generated by the compiler to check for discrepancies with the above references.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I have actually looked at the generated code and most of it I have figured out, but it is hard to know I actually have the general case well defined for all the various parameter types and combination, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Does this reference on [MIPS EABI for RedHat Linux](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/binutils/2003-06/msg00436.html) help?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not into MIPS, but maybe this [MIPS ABI History](https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/MIPS_ABI_History) reference might help.

Comment: This link does not work anymore. The new link seems to be: http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/MIPS_ABI_History