# What is the calling convention for the main function in C?

Tags: c, x86, calling-convention

Each function in C must have a calling convention, but what is the calling convention for the `main` function (I think it is the `cdecl` calling convention but I am not sure)?

Comment: The C language doesn't define any calling convention. You might want to add some more relevant tags and some more information in your question

Comment: `main` has the same calling convention as any other function; `_start` (a typical entry point in ELF), on the other hand, _is_ cdecl and must handle converting to the native calling convention for main (among other things) ... don't know why `_start` doesn't use the native calling convention... probably because in Linux, the binfmt_elf source is in the ./fs (file system) directory instead of ./arch and 32 bit x86 used cdecl, so it was easy to be lazy and force every non-cdecl platform to require some assembly or compiler specific intrinsics in their libc.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on the architecture and platform. A lot of x86 C runtime specifications require that main be `cdecl`, but it's by no means guaranteed.

The bottom line is you're not going to find this information in the C standard because the language is not tied to any one architecture. You might have more luck reading the documentation for the particular compiler(s) you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

C language does not define calling convention but the processor architecture and development platform does.
For X86 calling convention please check wiki
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Also, see ARM calling convention at below link http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf

More on calling convention see below wiki link
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention

Also, check discussion about MIPS calling convention at [GCC MIPS-32 Calling Conventions / Stack Frame Definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811424/gcc-mips-32-calling-conventions-stack-frame-definition)